# Truncated output in of Stream while using XmlTextWriter

Tags: c#

```
 using (Stream responseStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        XmlTextWriter xmlWriter;
                        xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(@"D:\DEmo.txt", new UTF8Encoding(true));
                        xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                        xmlWriter.IndentChar = '\t';
                        xmlWriter.Indentation = 1;
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("D", "multistatus", "DAV:");
                        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:M", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:");
                        foreach (IWebDAVStoreItem item in store.Root.Items)
                        {
                            if (item is Server.Stores.DiskStore.WebDAVDiskStoreDocument)
                            {

                                ((Server.Stores.DiskStore.WebDAVDiskStoreDocument)item).AddProperties(xmlWriter);

                            }
                        }
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();

                        responseStream.Flush();

                        responseStream.Position = 0;
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[responseStream.Length];
                        responseStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)responseStream.Length);
                        output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes); 
                        //output = (new StreamReader(responseStream)).ReadToEnd();
                        logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, "\n" + output);
                        responseStream.Close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {
                        logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, "\n" + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
```

I am trying to generate XML from above code but the reading from MemoryStream is not showing complete XML.Last part of XML content always get truncated doesn't matter how much big is the XML .I am not able to figure what is going on.Truncated output looks like this.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <D:multistatus xmlns:M="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:" xmlns:D="DAV:">         
    <D:response>
            <D:href>/ANSI-ISO C++ Professional Programmers Handbook.pdf</D:href>
            <D:propstat>
                <D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
                <D:prop>        
<M:Win32CreationTime>2014-06-28T14:30:09</M:Win32CreationTime>
                    <M:Win32LastAccess>2014-06-28T14:30:09</M:Win32LastAccess>
                        <M:Win32LastModifiedTime>2014-06-28T14:30:09</M:Win32La
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some part of the data might be still held in `XmlTextWriter`'s underlying stream's buffer. After you finish writing you should call [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.close.aspx) method of your `XmlTextWriter`. If you want to continue writing later but still want to ensure that all the data has been written you can use [`Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.flush.aspx).